# Tricky Firefox responsive layout issue with display table and max-width

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

I've wasted a lot of time with this problem, so my last step is to ask you guys out there. Maybe you can help me.

It's about this typical `css-table` problem, where firefox (and ie) won't render `max-width` correctly. I've already tried to implement `table-layout: fixed;` at nearly every position, but I don't get this baby running.

**Safari** displays everything perfectly and how i want it to be. But **Firefox** doesn't resize the image (in my fiddle i've marked the background RED when "it" happens) … and an unwanted horizontal scrollbar appears. (so you'll have to resize the window)
(Please note that setting the img width to 100% won't work for me, because smaller imgs will scale-up)

How can I make Firefox to resize the image correctly?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jk2hk77/

HTML:

```
<article>
    <div class="gallery" style="width: 400px;">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/267/">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="ctrl"></div>
         <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum …</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

SCSS:

```
article {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

    .gallery {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        max-width: 100%;

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        + div {
            margin-left: 30px;
            min-width: 200px;

            h2, p {
                max-width: 300px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.ctrl {
    width: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    float: right;
    background: black;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
```

Thank you guys for every idea i'll get!!

Comment: Can you explain what the specific behaviour you are expecting is? It isnt actually mentioned :S

Comment: It is, that on resizing the window, the image should also resize, so that no horizontal scrollbar appears! (it works correctly on safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY I've found the answer my self!

here is the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mkLdyqq0/

CHANGES IN HTML:

```
<div class="gallery" style="width: 400px;">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/267/">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

(img-Tag is now wrapped by another div-tag)

CHANGES IN SCSS:

```
article {
    …

    .gallery {
        …
        max-width: 100%;

        div {
            display: inline-table;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;

            img {
                …
            }
        }

        + div {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

Because of styling the wrapper-div with inline-table and table-layout:fixed … it "somehow" works.

WOHOOOO!

THX for all your inputs!!